# implementing Unmarshaller without using a temp struct

Tags: json, go, stack-overflow, unmarshalling

There is an Unmarshaller implementation down below because of `time.Unix` does only accepts seconds or nanoseconds but my data source is in milliseconds. Before asking my questions here is some code

Code:

```
type Platform struct {
    Status                CampaignStatus `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    TotalBudget           int            `json:"total_budget" bson:"totalBudget"`
    RemainingBudget       int            `json:"remaining_budget" bson:"remainingBudget"`
    MillisecondsStartDate int64          `json:"start_date"`
    StartDate             time.Time      `bson:"startDate"`
    MillisecondsEndDate   int64          `json:"end_date"`
    EndDate               time.Time      `bson:"endDate"`
    Audiance              Audiance       `json:"target_audiance" bson:"targetAudiance"` //typo?
    Creatives             Creatives      `json:"creatives" bson:"Creatives"`
    Insights              Insights       `json:"insights" bson:"insights"`
}

func (p *Platform) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {

    p2 := struct {
        Status                CampaignStatus `json:"status" bson:"status"`
        TotalBudget           int            `json:"total_budget" bson:"totalBudget"`
        RemainingBudget       int            `json:"remaining_budget" bson:"remainingBudget"`
        MillisecondsStartDate int64          `json:"start_date"`
        StartDate             time.Time      `bson:"startDate"`
        MillisecondsEndDate   int64          `json:"end_date"`
        EndDate               time.Time      `bson:"endDate"`
        Audiance              Audiance       `json:"target_audiance" bson:"targetAudiance"` //typo?
        Creatives             Creatives      `json:"creatives" bson:"Creatives"`
        Insights              Insights       `json:"insights" bson:"insights"`
    }{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &p2)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    p2.StartDate = time.Unix(0, p2.MillisecondsStartDate*int64(time.Millisecond/time.Nanosecond))
    p2.EndDate = time.Unix(0, p2.MillisecondsEndDate*int64(time.Nanosecond/time.Microsecond))

    *p = p2

    return
}
```

My questions are

1. Is there a way to implement Unmarshaller without creating a middle struct in this scenario? As you may see if I use the Platform type isntead of middle struct I get stack overflow error.
2. Could this approach ends up with memory leaks?

Comment: It is the proper way to handle the json in between before unmarshalling into main struct. Another way is to try with `interface{}` but that will require type assertion

Comment: Since both structs are the same (they have same fields), `*p = p2` should work.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian Yeah! You seem right. But it's somehow disturbing to me to define nearly same struct twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compose the fields that the marshaller can handle as an anonymous struct inside the `Platform` struct, something like:

```
type platformInner struct {
    Status                CampaignStatus `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    TotalBudget           int            `json:"total_budget" bson:"totalBudget"`
    RemainingBudget       int            `json:"remaining_budget" bson:"remainingBudget"`
    MillisecondsStartDate int64          `json:"start_date"`

    MillisecondsEndDate   int64          `json:"end_date"`

    Audiance              Audiance       `json:"target_audiance" bson:"targetAudiance"` //typo?
    Creatives             Creatives      `json:"creatives" bson:"Creatives"`
    Insights              Insights       `json:"insights" bson:"insights"`
}

type Platform struct {
    platformInner
    StartDate             time.Time      `bson:"startDate"`
    EndDate               time.Time      `bson:"endDate"`
}
```

And then in the custom unmarshaller, unmarshal into the nested struct, and set the other values.

```
func (p *Platform) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    var inner platformInner
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &inner)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    tmp := &Platform{
        innerPlatform: inner,
        StartDate:     time.Unix(0, inner.MillisecondsStartDate*int64(time.Millisecond/time.Nanosecond))
        EndDate:       time.Unix(0, inner.MillisecondsEndDate*int64(time.Nanosecond/time.Microsecond))
    }

    *p = tmp

    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of duplicating the struct definition for the anonymous "p2" struct type you could alias it under a new name, such as "PlatformTemp" like so:

```
func (p *Platform) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
  type PlatformTemp Platform
  var p2 PlatformTemp

  err = json.Unmarshal(b, &p2)
  // ...

  *p = Platform(p2)
  return nil
}
```

Since the types "Platform" and "PlatformTemp" have the same fields they can be assigned to each other with a simple cast; however, since "PlatformTemp" has no "UnmarshalJSON" method defined it will use the default unmarshaler.